# Looking for help with 2-tier clean URL's using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, rest

I am working on a site which will have two levels the URL reaches

My objective is to have clean URL's like this...

http://domain.com/username/dosomething

My ugly URL's currently look like this...

http://domain.com/index.php?page=username&command=dosomething

My attempt was this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&command=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$1/$2 index.php?page=$1&command=$2
```

Comment: A bit more detail is needed. Something like this is usually done in code by using a url router to map urls to handlers. Django(python) has this functionality built in as do a large number of other frameworks that claim to be "REST" based. Do you have a need to do this using apache ?

Comment: This isn't a very big site. Apache isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your backreferences correctly in the first part.  Backreferences are parenthesised expressions that will then get filled into $1, $2 et al. in the second part of the rule.  e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&command=$2
```

These parenthesized expressions match one or more non-/ characters and fill them into $1 and $2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you wrote but it broke my site and turned off CSS  this is what I wrote

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&command=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$1/$2 index.php?page=$1&command=$2

Comment: It probably rewrote CSS requests, which likely looked like `/style/sheet.css`, into `index.php?page=style&command=sheet.css`. You will need to designate an area that will **not** be rewritten with another rule preceding these, e.g. `RewriteRule ^/style/(.+) /style/$1 [L]` (untested, hope I got that right!)

Answer (score 0):

Your references are just referencing your entire URL so what you are telling it to give you is
index.php?page={entire URL}&command={null}

You need to setup the URL and only use parenthesis around the variables page and command. So
^domain.com/([username]+)/(dosomething)

then rewrite with:

http://domain.com/index.php?page=$1&command=$2

provided that your page and command variables are username and dosomething respectively